# how to attach an event listener to the DOM, depending upon the screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, ecmascript-6

for eg:`document.body.addEventListener('wheel', foo, {passive: true});`
This should be dynamically added/removed if the screen size is above `500px`

Comment: So add/remove it on resize....

Answer (score 6):

As @Rounin says, `window.matchMedia` is the equivalent of CSS @media queries. But the coolest part is not just that you can check with `.matches` -- the awesome thing is that *you can add an event-listener* that gets fired when the state changes.

You want something to happen when the screen width transition to above or below 500px -- you want to add a mouse wheel listener when the screen is >500px and remove it when the screen is <500px

You will also have to check for `.matches` initially to decide whether to add the listener or not when your page first loads, as @Rounin shows, but then the listener can be added and removed automatically based on matching the media query.

```
let widthMatch = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
// mm in the function arg is the matchMedia object, passed back into the function
widthMatch.addEventListener('change', function(mm) {
    if (mm.matches) {
        // it matches the media query: that is, min-width is >= 500px
        document.body.addEventListener( etc. );
    }
    else {
        // it no longer matches the media query
        // remove the event listener
    }
});
```

Comment: Really the best option !

Comment: **Note:** matchMedia is pretty [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia) including IE>=10

Comment: This solution covers everything.
However, 2 concerns:
  1. Mobile browsers are currently not supporting this. (We usually don't expect resizing on mobile. better have screen orientation in media query)
  2. Impact on performance. Will it be same overhead as adding a resize listener or more severe.

Comment: @ayush I don't know the performance impact without actually testing/measuring it, but I expect it would be significantly _less_ impactful than listening on resize.  The resize listening would happen internally to the browser and your listener code would be called far less often; only when the size crosses the threshold given in the media definition, instead of on every single resize.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getScreenWidth() {
  var w = window,
      d = document,
      e = d.documentElement,
      g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

  return w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth
}

function wheelListener() {
  console.log(getScreenWidth())
}

window.onresize = function() {
  if (getScreenWidth() > 500) {
    document.body.addEventListener('wheel', wheelListener, {passive: true})
  } else {
    document.body.removeEventListener('wheel', wheelListener)
  }
}

// to apply when the window loaded
window.onresize()
```

Comment: Thanks!!! yes, it helps but this solution doesn't dynamically adjusts adding/removing of that event handler upon resizing

Answer (score 2):

> how to attach an event listener to the DOM [...] only if the screen
>   size is above `500px`

`window.matchMedia` is the javascript equivalent of CSS `@media` queries.

For example, the following code verifies that the screen width is above `500px`.

```
var widerScreenWidth = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 501px)");

if (widerScreenWidth.matches) {

    // [... YOUR CODE HERE...]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have 3 options:

1. check the window size on load and add the listener if `> 500`: easiest solution but will not adjust if the user resizes the window.
2. add a listener to window resize and every time the width changes add or remove the `'wheel'` event listener depending on the width.
3. always add an event listener to `'wheel'`, but inside the event callback, check for the width every time the callback runs before executing your logic

Comment: note that listening to wheel and resize events can have a big performance cost, so best to throttle or debouce the callback

Comment: option 2 looks good with throttle added as @MichaelJasper pointed out.
Ruling out option 3 just because their isn't any app logic. just adding/removing event listeners for performance optimization.